# SQL Server, how to get younger users?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get users from a younger country for example I have the following tables.

[image: Users table]

[image]

If there is more than one user of the youngest who have the same age, they should also be shown

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post your tables as images. Use formatted text for this.

Comment: Show the query you've tried..

Comment: How do you define age?

Comment: @gordon I think we have a language barrier here. Based on the example, I think OP wants the youngest, ie *eariest*, birthday, so the *oldest* people.

Comment: @Bohemian . . . I wasn't actually referring to youngest vs. oldest.  Ages don't have to be counted in complete years, so the calculation is not precise.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query, get `MIN` birthday on subquery then `self join` on users table.

```
select u.idcountry,t.name,u.username, (DATEPART(year, getdate()) - t.years) 'age'
from 
(
SELECT u.idcountry,c.name,DATEPART(year, u.birthday) as 'years',count(*) as 'cnt'
FROM users u inner join country c on u.idcountry = c.idcountry
group by u.idcountry,c.name,DATEPART(year, u.birthday)
) t inner join users u on t.idcountry = u.idcountry and t.years = DATEPART(year, u.birthday)
where t.cnt > 1
```

sqlfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9baab959f79b1fa8c28ed87a8640e85d

Comment: This query uses birth year rather than age. Users born the same year will have different ages depending on whether the month and day are before or after today.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`rank()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function:

```
select ...
from ...
where rank() over (partition by idcountry order by birthday) = 1
```

Rows with the same birthday in a country are ranked the same, so this returns all youngest people with if there’s more than one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky.  I would use window functions -- count the people of a particular age and choose the ones where there are duplicates for the youngest.

You don't specify how to define age, so I'll just use the earliest calendar year:

```
select u.*
from (select u.*,
             count(*) over (partition by idcountry, year(birthday)) as cnt_cb,
             rank() over (partition by idcountry order by year(birthday)) as rnk
      from users u
     ) u
where cnt_cb > 1 and rnk = 1;
```

I'll let you handle the joins to bring in the country name.

Comment: Most commonly, age isn't just calculated from the first of the year in which they were born, but also the month and day. If my birthday were today, I would be one year older than I was yesterday.

Comment: @DanGuzman . . . I wouldn't necessarily just use years for counting ages.  The OP's example returns as a tie two people born in the same year.  The OP should clarify the definition.  Note: if the OP uses `datediff()` in SQL Server, it is equivalent to the definition I am using.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data and desired results show the oldest users within each country when more than one of the oldest have the same age. The query below will do that, assuming age is calculated using full birth date.

```
WITH
    users AS (
        SELECT 
              username
            , birthday
            , idcountry
            , (CAST(CONVERT(char(8),GETDATE(),112) AS int) - CAST(CONVERT(char(8),birthday,112) AS int)) / 10000 AS age
            , RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY idcountry ORDER BY (CAST(CONVERT(char(8),GETDATE(),112) AS int) - CAST(CONVERT(char(8),birthday,112) AS int)) / 10000 DESC) AS age_rank
        FROM dbo.Users
    )
    , oldest_users AS (
        SELECT
              username
            , birthday
            , idcountry
            , age
            , COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY idcountry, age_rank ORDER BY age_rank) AS age_count
        FROM users
        WHERE age_rank = 1
    )
SELECT
      c.idcountry
    , c.name
    , oldest_users.age
    , oldest_users.username
FROM oldest_users
JOIN dbo.Country AS c ON c.idcountry = oldest_users.idcountry
WHERE
    oldest_users.age_count > 1;
```